# how to prevent cron job email splitting into multiple lines

Tags: cron, email, postfix, smtp

CRON has emailed me the extract below :

```
May 12 04:27:54 rpi postfix/smtpd[9343]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
unknown[95.211.213.214]: 504 5.5.2 <WIN-HBAL58UG0JH>: Helo command rejected: need
fully-qualified hostname; from=<admin@goodservers.com> to=<holly.jihad@gmail.com>
proto=ESMTP helo=<WIN-HBAL58UG0JH>
May 12 04:27:54 rpi postfix/smtpd[9345]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
unknown[95.211.213.214]: 504 5.5.2 <WIN-HBAL58UG0JH>: Helo command rejected: need
fully-qualified hostname; from=<admin@goodservers.com> to=<holly.jihad@gmail.com>
proto=ESMTP helo=<WIN-HBAL58UG0JH>
May 12 04:27:54 rpi postfix/smtpd[9343]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
unknown[95.211.213.214]: 504 5.5.2 <WIN-HBAL58UG0JH>: Helo command rejected: need
fully-qualified hostname; from=<admin@goodservers.com> to=<holly.jihad@gmail.com>
proto=ESMTP helo=<WIN-HBAL58UG0JH>
```

It was split unto multiple lines, for every entry like above, it made viewing the email somewhat harder. Is it possible to prevent these newlines?

The CRON job is simply a command :

```
muhammad@rpi ~ $ cat /etc/cron.daily/mail-important-logs 
#!/bin/sh

# filter out useful logs and email me
cat /var/log/mail.log | grep reject
```

Comment: What was the cron job like? That could help explaining the output you observed. Also, can you confirm that the extra newlines are in the actual e-mail that cron sent, and are not a feature of your MUA?

Comment: @dhag I have updated my question. I do not know what a MUA is, please if you could clarify.

Comment: I meant, is it possible that it's the program you use to read e-mails that wraps lines when displaying them, rather than cron?

Comment: @dhag no idea, I am using postfix + dovecot + squirrel mail, all pretty standard applications.

Comment: Then you can use Squirrel to "show source", or whatever is closest, and see whether the lines are wrapped in the original e-mail. I would say it's much less likely that either of the other programs you mentioned are guilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dhag was on the right lines. It was squirrelmail wrapping the lines, when I exported the email it had no wrapping. Later I found a setting under options, which when I set really high took away the wrapping for my cron job logs.

[image]

But this has the side effect that now all your emails are not wrapped up to that limit, unless the sender has manual new lines inserted.